# Using ls to find files that end in a character, ignoring extension

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

I am supposed to use ls to find files that end in a certain letter, but it does not matter if the file has an extension or not.

For example, I want it to do this

`> ls
test test.txt test.ascii other.txt`

`> ls [something]
test test.txt test.ascii`

So that I can find files that end with a 't', but it doesn't include the file where the extension ends in t

Edit:
I am supposed to assume that the only period characters in the filename will be for the extension and there will be no others

Comment: If you had `test.foo.bar`, is `.foo.bar` the extension or `.bar`?

Comment: `.bar` would be, I forgot to mention I am assuming that there is no other period characters in the file names other than the one for the extension, if there is one

Comment: Just in the current  directory ?

Comment: What exactly are you supposed to use? Only `ls` and its options? Does the person who set this homework know that usually wildcards and pipes are handled by the shell, not `ls` (with exceptions like GNU `ls`'s `--hide`/`--ignore` options)?

Comment: The only thing stated was 'use ls'. There is very little help at times which is frustrating and the common  response for help is "try looking online"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something=

```
 |grep -e ".*t\.[^.]*" -e "^[^.]*t$"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `bash` shell, you can use the `extglob` option to do a complex filter. For example:

**Solution:**

```
bash$ shopt -s extglob

bash$ ls
other.txt  test  test.ascii  test.txt

bash$ ls *@(t.*|[^.]?[[:alnum:]]t)
test  test.ascii  test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

PATTERN1 `(t.*)` matches any file ending with a "t" followed by a file extension:

```
bash$ ls *@(t.*)
test.ascii  test.txt
```

PATTERN2 `([^.]?[[:alnum:]]t)` matches any file that does NOT have a dot, followed by zero or more alphanumeric chars, and ending in a "t". This matches files that do not have a file extension:

```
bash$ ls *@([^.]?[[:alnum:]]t)
test
```

The glob `@(PATTERN1|PATTERN2)` matches either pattern exactly once. The combined pattern filters out only what we're looking for.

For more info on bash patterns, see: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

Comment: This will not match `foot.t` for example.

Comment: yes, it does match `foot.t`, due to the fact that PATTERN1 matches. Verified.

Comment: Sorry, I fumbled with the example, wrong example. You are assuming that the extension may be 1, 2, or 3 characters but the pattern will fail with anything longer even if the filename does not end in a `t`. Test with this files `touch never.abc{det,t}`.

Comment: Also, the pattern will match `tt.none.never`, which may be argued that it does not end with t just before the extension. And, will match filenames with many dots `one.two.broken.print`. Maybe a pattern is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Ageed. I would personally pipe to `grep -E ...`. Bash patterns aren't nearly as powerful as a true regex. I was curious of the problem could be solved purely with `ls` and no pipe, and I guess the answer is... "almost" :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need files with only one dot (extension) and
Assuming that you need to search on the present directory (./) you may use:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './[^.]*t\(\.[^.]*\)?'
./test.txt
./test.ascii
./test
```

This could be used but will include directories (and will fail if filenames have newlines):

```
$ printf '%s\n' * | grep -e ".*t\.[^.]*" -e "^[^.]*t$"
test
test.ascii
test.txt
tt
```

To allow filenames with newlines use (GNU grep):

```
$ printf '%s\0' * | grep -ze ".*t\.[^.]*" -e "^[^.]*t$" | xargs -0
test test.ascii test.txt tt
```